# "def save" - Detect if a field is completely blank - Django

Tags: django, django-models, field

In my Django models, I have a def save function. I need this function to see if a field is left blank completely. I need it to see if a field has been left blank every single entry and then return something to an HTML file. I'll attach my code below but I'm really stumped. I'm not sure how I can set a value in that function and get it all the way to my HTML. Is there an easier way?

models.py

```
class Data_Repo1(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=True, related_name="Data_Repo1", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    date1 = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    date2 = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pk']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.date1 or 'None'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('repo1')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.date1 is None:
            #Something Here - "self.date1 = NONE"
        else:
            return
        if self.date2 is None:
            #Something Here - "self.date2 = NONE"
        else:
            return

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
```

views.py

def repo1(request):
context = {}

```
context['Add_Repo'] = Add_Repo.objects.filter(user=request.user)
context['Data_Repo1'] = Data_Repo1.objects.filter(user=request.user)
context['Field_Repo1'] = Field_Repo1.objects.filter(user=request.user)

if self.date1 is None: #NOT WORKING
    print('TEST') #NOT WORKING

return render(request, 'sheets/list_repo/repo1.html', context)
```

HTML

```
{% for post in Data_Repo1 %}
        {% if date1 == 'NONE' %}
            <h1>ITS HERE</h1>
        {% endif %}
        <tr>
            <td><div><a href="{% url 'update_extinguisher' pk=post.pk %}" style="color: black;">{% if post.date1 %}{{ post.date1 }}{%else%}<span style="color: transparent;">None</span>{%endif%}</a></div></td>
            <td><div><a href="{% url 'update_extinguisher' pk=post.pk %}" style="color: black;">{% if post.date2 %}{{ post.date2 }}{%else%}<span style="color: transparent;">None</span>{%endif%}</a></div></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @RussellHertel. You have done it correctly defining your `models` and retrieving value in `views.py` and iterating in HTML using Django template language. Only this piece in your HTML is incorrect `{% if date1 == 'NONE' %}` to correct it you may do it as `{% if post.date1 == 'NONE' %}`

Comment: @AhemdAblak I am getting the error "name 'self' is not defined" it is referring to my views.py. Since this is in my for loop in HTML won't it just checks each one at a time and return none if it is blank. I need to loop through all of them first to see if all of that field is blank and then return a value to my HTML if that field is blank. Will this do that? Do I need a for loop in my views? Thank you

Comment: Hi @RussellHertel, you are already iterating in the html at `{% for post in Data_Repo1 %}`. For the `self` error you are receiving in `views.py`, you may replace  `if self.date1 is None:` with `if context['Data_Repo1'].data1 is None:`

Comment: @AhmedAblak So we are really close. I made the changes but I'm now getting the error "'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'data1'". Also, what do I put in the if statement to detect if the field is empty for every entry and return one value?

Comment: Hi @RussellHertel, the error is because of a typo `data1` should be `date1`. in `if context['Data_Repo1'].data1 is None:` For empty field detection and as per your models, it will be a blank and accordingly, you can use the following to validate empty field: `if context['Data_Repo1'].data1 == "":` I will add the answer with sample for more clarification.

Comment: @AhmedAblak Sorry for the late response. Everything is running with no errors but even when the fields are empty it isn't printing anything.

Comment: Are you running the application locally or are you using a web server?

Comment: @AhmedAblak I'm running it locally for now.

Comment: hi @ RussellHertel, can you please try to print the values of `repo.date1` and`repo.date2` before the `if` statement inside the `for` loop and show the types as well as follows: `print(repo.date1)`  then `print(repo.date2)` then `print(type(repo.date1))` then `print(type(repo.date2))`.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the following minor amendment to your code to cover the validation of of empty dates and iterate over the list of repos:

```
context['Add_Repo'] = Add_Repo.objects.filter(user=request.user)
context['Data_Repo1'] = Data_Repo1.objects.filter(user=request.user)
context['Field_Repo1'] = Field_Repo1.objects.filter(user=request.user)
for repo in context['Data_Repo1']:
    if repo.date1 == "" and repo.date2 == "":
        print("Repo: {} has empty date1 and date2".format(repo.pk))
        continue
    if repo.date1 == "":
        print("Repo: {} has empty date1".format(repo.pk))
        continue
    if repo.date2 == "":
        print("Repo: {} has empty date2".format(repo.pk))

return render(request, 'sheets/list_repo/repo1.html', context)
```